# Django can't recognize 0,1,2 precisely in url

Tags: django, url

```py
my_app/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect


articles = {
    'index' : "Hello this is a view inside my_app",
    'simple' : 'simple views',
    'sports' : 'Sports Page',
    'finance' : 'Finance Page',
    'politics' : "Politics Page"
}

def news_view(request, topic) :
    try :
        return HttpResponse(articles[topic]) 
    except:
        raise Http404("404 GENERIC ERROR") 

def num_page_view(request,num):
    topics_list = list(articles.keys())
    topic = topics_list[num]
   
    return HttpResponseRedirect(topic)
```

```
my_app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:num>',views.num_page_view),
    path('<str:topic>/',views.news_view),
]
```

when i type `/my_app/0`, django automatically change `0` `0/`, so i think Django can't recognize that this page's parameter is pure `int`. It continues until I type `0,1,2`

But when i type more than 2 (ex. `/my_app/3`), it works as i intended
(1. enter `/my_app/3` 2. redirect to `/my_app/finance/`)

I don't know why Django do recognize the int parameter more than 2 but not 0,1,2.

Expected

1. enter `/my_app/0`
2. redirect to `/my_app/index/`

But...

1. enter `my_app/0`
2. url is automatically changed to `my_app/0/`
3. can't redirect to the page so i got an error

Comment: Am I right in assuming you've made some changes in your code and would previously have correctly gotten a 404 error? This is not a problem of Django not understanding that your argument is supposed to be an int, by default Django redirects you to a url with a trailing slash if your url doesn't have one. See: [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#append-slash). Ideally all your url patterns should end in a slash

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. Here is a workaround

1. In urls.py add a trailing slash

> urlpatterns = [
> path('int:num_page/', views.num_page_view) ]

2. In views.py

> Blockquote

```
 def num_page_view(request, num_page):
        topics_list = list(articles.keys())
        topic = topics_list[int(num_page)]
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/first_app/{topic}')
```